# Rendering very large model of Blender in Three.js

Tags: json, webgl, three.js

I have a very big Blender model (the json about 70 Mb). Can Three.js normally render such model? Load model with the following code:

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

callbackDice = function(geometry) {
    createMesh(geometry);
};
loader.load(file, callbackDice);

function createMesh(geometry) {
     mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, wireframe: false } ));                   
     mesh.overdraw = true;
     scene.add(mesh);                    
 }
```

I can not approximate the shape to reduce the number of primitives that describe it (each primitive has its own color which changes dynamically). The following code changes the color of primitives

```
for ( var i = 0; i < mesh.geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    var face = mesh.geometry.faces[ i ];
    face.color.setHex('0x'+ color value);
}
mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

If using Three.js is not possible, please advise any other library for working with WebGL for solving this problem.

Comment: May I know how did you able to read/write 70 mb JSON file ? I am facing with opening/reading JSON file of 4 mb.

Comment: @Valay Are you interested in how I bring the file or how much time it is rendered?

Comment: I am interested in how you bring the file. Actually I am not using `JSONLoader()`. I've a js file with a single function which returns json object. But there are 18000 objects and each object has 15 members/properties.

Comment: First, I have just a set of vectors and surfaces. Then, using [JSON Model format 3.1](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3.1) I create json file that describes my model. Transfer the file to the script by GET request.

Answer (score 0):

That must be possible with `BufferGeometry`. Take a look at the [webgl_buffergeometry](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry.html) example. It renders 160000 triangles, each with it's own color. The BufferGeometry doesn't support wireframe and flat shading, though.